# Sending JSON to Bundle as serializable

Tags: android, serialization

I have a class that extends JSONObject and implements MyInterface, I have to send an object of my class as a bundle to another activity as serializable.

```
class MyClass extends JSONObject implements MyInterface{} 
interface MyInterface implements Serializable{}
```

I have to send the object of Myclass from one activity to another which has implementation `(MyInterface)getSerializable("data")`, problem what I am facing is I am the object which I received on second activity is empty.
In my first activity i am putting object as -- `bundle.putSerializableExtra("data",new MyClass(testData))`

Activity1

```
    `Intent i = new Intent(activity, TestActivity.class)try {
             Data param =new Data("{\n" +
                    "  \"test\": \"hello\",\n" +
                    "  \"datalist\": [\n" +
                    "    {\n" +
                    "      \"test\": \"hello\"\n" +
                    "    },\n" +
                    "    {\n" +
                    "      \"test\": \"hello\"\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "  ]\n" +
                    "}");
            i.putExtra("test1",param);
            i.putExtra("test2",param.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        activity.startActivity(i);
`
```

TestActivityCode--

```
`var data: MyInterface? = 
                 intent?.extras?.getSerializableExtra("test1") as MyInterface?`
```

Data Class

```
       `class Data extends JSONObject implements MyInterface {
public Data(String data) throws JSONException {
        super(data);
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your object like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ChatListDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("data", testData);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Get `getSerializable` like this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
           testData1 = (YorClassName) bundle.getSerializable("data");
        }
```

Comment: Please check your passing data is blank or not @NehaRathore

Comment: already checked before putting extra data is there, also send via converting into string, and in string i got that data , but i have to do it via seriablizable only

Comment: Please update your question with your current data send and get code. @NehaRathore